# GoogleMaps old behaviour, when I tap a marker

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, marker, gmsmapview

I'm using xcode 9.0, GoogleMaps SDK 2.5.0 and GooglePlaces 2.5.0.

In the method `func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool` I'm trying to disable the auto center map, when I select a marker and go back to the old behaviour of only showing the marker and no auto center enabled. The problem is that the marker doesn't appear when I implement that behaviour (lines that are commented), all stack overflow I searched implements those lines. I'm lost

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate
{

    //MARK: Class Life Cycle

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        setupUI()
        setupMap()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //MARK: -Setup

    func setupUI() {
        navigationController?.hideBar()
    }

    func setupMap() {
        let map = MapManager.sharedInstance.setupMap(view: mapView, latitude: GoogleMap.latitude, longitude: GoogleMap.longitude, zoom: GoogleMap.zoom)
        map.delegate = self
        mapView.addSubview(map)

        MapManager.sharedInstance.setupMapMarkers(map: map, file: File.geoFence, fileType: File.json)
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
        //        mapView.selectedMarker = marker
        //        return true

        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone comes across this odd bug, the odd solution is adding the delegate again:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
    mapView.delegate = self
    mapView.selectedMarker = marker
    return true

    return false
}
```